# Determine if a Google Apps Script WebApp is running in /dev mode

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Is there any way to determine whether a web app is running in dev mode or as a properly published version?

I tried getting the URL at both front and back ends.

If I query

```
window.location.href
```

at the front end I don't get the URL displayed in the page address bar, which ends in /dev or /exec. Instead I get a URL that ends in /userCodeAppPanel - I'm guessing because it's been sanitized.

If I call the backend

```
ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
```

and pass it to the front end it always shows the /exec URL, even if the script is in /dev mode.

I wanted to set DEBUG flags on or off depending on which mode the script was running in.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can determine if the WebApp is in dev mode if it is not executable by other users but only the owner of the script. Check the documentation- [Using the Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api) and [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44491276/5995040) for additional details. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the other problem.   I get the dev mode URL when I deploy my script as a web app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the need to determine if the script is in dev mode as well and couldn't find a solution either. But here's a work around that would work. It requires a manual step every time you publish a production version.

During development:

- Set a dev flag to true.
- Code that need to be aware of the dev/production mode needs to check that flag.

Before publishing:

- Set the dev flag to false.
- Publish the web app.

After publishing:

- Revert the dev flag to true.

This would allow segmentation of resources used by dev and production versions.